# Why does the Community user on Meta has 3 reputation?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, meta

[The Community user on Meta](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) has 3 reputation. Isn't it supposed to have 1 reputation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This usually happens when posts and suggested edits are attributed to the Community user (as part of the procedure followed when deleting a user). This will eventually be fixed by a scheduled task and the reputation will go back to 1.

Comment: *This will eventually be fixed by a scheduled task and the reputation will go back to 1.*

Comment: It appears the reputation is still 3, a year later.

Comment: And it is still at 3 after four years.

Comment: It's still 3, and it never will change. This is a bug. No other sites or meta sites have this problem.